# Typescript: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I've seen about 10 questions about this, but they don't seem to explain my situation.
I have a variable `admin` with a type `PlayerType` that I set later, but get the error:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'never'
```

Even though I clearly check if it is set and do set it if it exists in the data...

Sample code ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hopper-ppgmt?file=/src/App.tsx)):

```js
// My type
type PlayerType = {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  user: {
    name: string;
  };
};
// My code
let admin: PlayerType | null = null;

const players: PlayerType[] = [ // For demo, this info comes from server
    { isAdmin: false, user: { name: `John` } },
    { isAdmin: true, user: { name: `Jane` } }
];

players.map((player) => {
    if (player.isAdmin) {
      admin = player;
    }
    return player;
});

if (admin) {
    console.log(admin.user.name);
}
```

The error shows up on the `admin.user` of the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find` instead, and let TypeScript infer the type automatically, which will be `PlayerType | undefined`.

```
const admin = players.find(player => player.isAdmin);
if (admin) {
    console.log(admin.user.name);
}
```

`.map` is only for when you need to construct a new array by transforming every element of another array - which isn't what you're trying to do here.

Getting type to work with TypeScript often works best when values are constructed and assigned *functionally* and with `const`s.

Another option is to avoid the callback:

```
for (const player of players) {
  if (player.isAdmin) {
    admin = player;
  }
}
if (admin) {
  console.log(admin.user.name);
}
```

The problem with `.map`, and with callbacks in general, is that TS doesn't know if or when the callback will be called. The best approach is to use a method that returns the value you're looking for, rather than to try to achieve multiple things at once type-wise, which TypeScropt has problems with.